Should we make personal anecdotes a no-no?
A moron (full disclosure: me) just vented personal anecdote in an answer, pretending it crypto-related when that's, at best, about computer security, with a mere 6 characters on crypto. 
Should he be

politely asked to refrain from that next time
asked to remove the irrelevant prose, which is in too small characters anyway 
receive a formal reprimand and have his answer summarily modded out
banned for life and his posts burninated
sued.


Burninating all the posts is actually something that only devs / CMs can do on SE once a user crosses a certain (low) rep threshold :p

Just put up the disclaimer of experience.
Personal anecdotes are valuable as they generally reflect human nature and how people actually behave.  In the case of cryptography, this is less important than in information security because security is rooted in policy and not cryptography.
You can find all of the theory in a field by books, but if you really want to learn what's important, find someone who worked in that field.  
